# How to re-enable CoreLocation prompt in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-location

When I first ran my app that uses CoreLocation in the iPhone simulator, I was prompted with the dialog saying that my app would like to use my current location.  In that popup, there is a checkbox that says never ask again.  I had that checkbox selected, and now I never receive that popup again.  How can I revert this change?  I'd like to see the popup again to do some testing.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the app and running it again will do it, or you can go into Settings -> General -> Reset and tap "Reset Location Warnings" (which will reset it for all apps.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Your solution worked for testing the app on my iPhone.  But, do you know where I can find a similar setting for the iPhone simulator?  In the iPhone simulator, under Settings -> General, there's no item for "Reset".

Comment: I found the answer to my question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763733/how-to-reset-iphone-simulator  ..  apparently you have to reset it in the OSX's System Preferences --> Security --> Reset Warnings!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. But I found changing simulator version from 4.3 to 5.1 fixed the problem temporarily.