# Clear iPhone simulator cookies

Tags: iphone, nshttpcookie

I have an app that makes request to a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) service. Authentication is done using cookies. This already works.

What I have problems with is to test the case when the cookie is no longer valid and my code has to reauthenticate. To test this I have to wait until the cookie is invalid, which could take some time. To accelerate this I figured that if I delete the cookie it would have the same effect.

How to delete all cookies of an app on the iPhone simulator?

I already tried the following:

Deleting <app-dir>/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies doesn't work. It seems that my cookies are never written to this file.

Deleting all cookies in NSHTTPCookieStorage on app startup doesn't work either.

Comment: Is there some reason resetting the simulator won't work for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cookies are located at:

**`/Users/<YourUsername>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOSversion>/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies`**

You may need to quit out of Safari (in the fast app switching area) and then delete them so Safari won't have them in memory.

Comment: That seemed to work only for SDKs prior 4.x. I have that file but it wasn't updated since spring.

Comment: Deleting Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies definitely works for me, se above.

Comment: Thx Matthew, you got me a step further. Your directories only work for Safari in my own app these dirs are .../4.2/Applications/<app hash>/Library/Cookies/. I deleted the .dat files that I didn't see before I reseted my simulator. After that my app doesn't save cookies between app starts anymore. Kind of what I need for testing. But it is definitely a strange behavior.

Comment: Ah, interesting, and definitely strange. Glad you found a solution, anyway.

Comment: The cookie file can be found at:  > /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/4.2/Applications/<app_id>/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies

Comment: @Balint Right, that's what my answer says.

Comment: There is no iPhone Simulator folder in Application Support. Where else could it be?

Comment: @modiX This answer was from 2010. A _lot_ has changed since then. *Resetting the simulator is likely your best bet*. If you need to delete single cookies while keeping other things in place, you should be able to find them in `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICEIDENTIFIERHERE/data/Library/Cookies`. Replace "DEVICEIDENTIFIERHERE" with the 37-character UUID directory name for that device. You'll be able to spot the right one if you just sort by "Date Modified" in the Finder.

Answer (score 22):

***YOU CAN RESET THE SIMULATOR***

- Launch the simulator.
- Click the FIRST item on the "menu bar". It says "iOS Simulator"
- A menu will appear.  Go down three items to "Reset Contents and Settings"
- Click "Reset" on the dialog which appears

[image: iPhone Simulator Reset Cookies]

Comment: Resetting it is indeed likely the easiest route unless you don't want to reset everything else in the simulator.

Comment: That is not an option, I need to have the rest of my content not deleted. Though I could copy it back after reset.

Comment: No I have various files (e.g. sqlite dbs) that save user data which are necessary for my tests.

Comment: This answer seems to be out of date. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763733/how-to-reset-iphone-simulator

Answer (score 14):

You'll probably find better luck doing this in the SDK code rather than modifying file systems.
Try:

```
    //Delete previous cookies
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in [[[cookieStorage cookiesForURL:YOUR_URL] copy] autorelease]) {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
    }
```

Comment: Works like charm. You save my day!!

Answer (score 2):

I just used [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) to inspect what happens to the iPhone Simulator filesystem when the "Clear Cookies and Data" button is tapped. These commands replicate that behavior, however, there is a trick:

```
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library/Cookies"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library/Caches/Snapshots"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobilesafari"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library/WebKit"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library/Safari"
```

The Simulator **needs to be restarted**. So, *before* manipulating the filesystem, I run this:

```
killall "iPhone Simulator"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the home screen, then the settings app. Tap Safari, then scroll down to Clear Cookies. I'm not sure where the cookie file is on the filesystem, <s>somewhere under /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform I'd expect</s> (see Matthew Frederick's answer).

Comment: This was my thought as well, but it doesn't seem to actually clear the cookies when I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the simulator in newer MacOS versions:

Launch the simulator.

- Click "Device" on the "menu bar".
- A menu will appear. Go down two items to "Erase All Contents and Settings..."
- Click "Reset" on the dialog which appears

[image: how to reset ios simulator]

Answer (score -1):

Why not force cookie expiration to a low value for testing?

That is exactly the same then.