# Delete simulator Safari cookies and caches

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, ios-simulator, nshttpcookie

I need to delete simulator cookies whenever needed. I need to delete the Facebook cookie from the iOS simulator.

I tried the following code, and it does not works.

```
- (IBAction)Logout:(id)sender {

     NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
     for (NSHTTPCookie *each in [[cookieStorage cookiesForURL:@"Facebook.com"] copy ]) {
         [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
     }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear iphone simulator cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427165/clear-iphone-simulator-cookies)

Comment: Do you delete the Facebook cookies , I have the same problem .