# iOS Simulator: Invalid device state

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I just downloaded Xcode 6.4 from App Store and started to create a hello world app to learn swift but I get the error saying "Invalid Device State".

[image: Screenshot 1]

I googled a lot and tried the below things:

1. Restarted Mac and entered xcode and started project (as mentioned in a stack overflow thread)
2. I created a new iOS app with another layout but showed the same error again if I ran that project.
3. I deleted all projects and re-installed Xcode again. Started a new project and ran it but still getting the same error.

I am running Yosemite 10.10.1 and the Xcode version is 6.4.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Device State - Xcode/iOS Simulator error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480245/invalid-device-state-xcode-ios-simulator-error)

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480245/invalid-device-state-xcode-ios-simulator-error/36352622#36352622

Answer (score 4):

Devices can get stuck in the creating state if errors occur in older versions of Xcode.  This was fixed at some point in Xcode 7, but I'm not sure if the fix made it back into an Xcode 6.x release.

From Terminal.app, please run 'xcrun simctl list'.  Locate the UDID of the device that you are attempting to boot.  If it is stuck in the 'Creating' state, you can try recreating it by running 'xcrun simctl erase '.

If it is stuck in a different state, please update your question appropriately to indicate which state the device is stuck in.

On a side note, I suggest you update your OS.  There have been a lot of quality fixes since 10.10.1.  10.10.5 just came out.

Comment: sudo xcrun simctl erase 5EFC9DAA-82D6-4C8C-9B83-13231A52B8A6
Password:
Invalid device: 5EFC9DAA-82D6-4C8C-9B83-13231A52B8A6

Comment: it doesn't work, it just says the devices are invalid.

Comment: I've restarted and deleted all xcode components that I can find.  I'm about to half to reformat my computer

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons a simple comp restart did the trick for me.

Comment: I tried restarting about 4 times.  I never could fix this issue.

Comment: Restarting the computer should have no effect.  Run 'xcrun simctl erase [UDID]' to erase your simulator device to its defaults state.

Comment: Andrew, if you still have problems, provide more details.  What do you see in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log ?  What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list' etc.  If nothing seems to work, file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com including a sysdiagnose and the CoreSimulator.log, and mention the radar number here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch from your original simulator to new one (for example from iphone 6 to 6plus) and then switch back to original one (iphone 6) and it should be ok