# Invalid Device State in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcode7.3

I am running Xcode 7.3 and Xcode 8.0 with two different windows. But when building in on Xcode, another is not finding simulator. Another problem is indexing when running project in Xcode 7.3 and showing:

> Invalid Device State

[image]

How could the problem be solved???

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480245/invalid-device-state-xcode-ios-simulator-error

Comment: This happened for me also when using Xcode 7.3 and Xcode 8 at a same time. Try Quit  one and work with single Xcode at a time.

Comment: Yap!.. I do this and now it happens

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this problem.
To fix this,

1. Quit Project
2. Quit Xcode
3. Launch Xcode and click preference..,
4. Go to "Location" Tab, Select correct options from "Command Line Tools"
   dropdown
5. Quit Xcode and relaunch it. Run your app.

Its now working fine..