# Error on emulating ios in ionic (Invalid device state)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to emulate project on mac, ionic gets error:

```
No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6s-Plus, 9.3 simulator

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/Alex/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/04A637E3-A6C4-4180-AAB7-E50164F4DD0F/system.log'
```

But building and adding platform is successfully ended.

Comment: did you tried in xcode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Device State - Xcode/iOS Simulator error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480245/invalid-device-state-xcode-ios-simulator-error)