# Can't run app in iOS 11.0 simulator

Tags: ios11, xcode9

I can't run the application on the simulator in the new xCode 9 beta 3 (9M174d). Every time I see the error message: (Mach error -308 - (ipc / mig) server died)

[image]

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/24033417/5523205 answer. It may help you.

Comment: shahrukh, I tried, it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this issue after installing XCode 9 beta 4. Tried every possible suggestion. The only thing that solved this issue for me was to reinstall Xcode command line tools:

Open terminal and type the command: `xcode-select --install`

After installation reboot the mac.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed after installing the latest Mac Os Sierra patches.

Comment: Having the same issue with XCode 9 beta 4. Sierra patches already installed, it didn't help.