# Simulator needs reboot on restart (react-native run-ios)

Tags: react-native

Each time I quit the simulator and run `react-native run-ios` simulator freezes with a black screen.

I have to manually go to Hardware > Reboot to get everything going.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue, if you haven't added too much stuff to your project, I invite you to start over, in a new folder and with a new simulator, also see [How to reset iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763733/how-to-reset-iphone-simulator)

Comment: I have tried all those options. But still the issue persists.