# Expo or yarn cache causes lots of confusing bugs. When do I have to clear it?

Tags: react-native, expo, push, yarnpkg, ota

I'm publishing an app using Expo managed workflow.

Today I pushed an update from the master branch to the default release channel using `expo publish`.

I ran it on the Expo app and noticed that the app was crashing due to a bug I had been working on earlier in the day. This bug was part of a work in progress committed in a separate feature branch. It involves some new dependencies.

Upon further inspection I noticed that my local master branch also had the bug, despite not having the commit.

The problem was solved after I ran the following *and* [reset the simulators content and settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763733/how-to-reset-iphone-simulator):

`rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn && expo r -c`

But I still don't know what the issue is or how to prevent it.